# Execute code asynchronously and return MVC action

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC application in which when a certain URL is visited, I want to begin running some initialisation code that takes around 4 seconds, but also return the `View()` to them immediately. Currently, I am doing this:

```
public IActionResult Inbound(string uuid)
{
    using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://.../call/setup"))
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("uuid", uuid);
        Clients.httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Setup([FromHeader] string uuid)
{
    InitialiseStuff(uuid); //This takes several seconds to execute
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

Is this the most optimal way of doing so? The initialisation code does not affect the view returned from ‘inbound’.

**Just to clarify:** I want to return the view and then initialise some unrelated code in the background. Currently, I am just making an async GET request to a separate action that then executes the code. I want to know if this is the best solution.

Comment: Can’t you do it in the Startup class?

Comment: I don't think so, because `InitialiseStuff()` requires `uuid`

Comment: and what is your question? problem?

Comment: You cannot. You can only return from the action once you have completely done everything. Whether it is async or not makes no difference. If you start some operation, async or sync, the MVC engine will wait until the whole thing is done. There are hacky ways to do what you want but the correct way would be to leave a signal, such as something in a message queue, and return the view. Another application, a windows service, can be reading the queue to do the additional work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to send a page with no content in it, and when the page is loaded make ajax call to get contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Start a new Thread for `InitialiseStuff()`, a samll sample like below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Setup([FromHeader] string uuid)
    {
        InitialiseStuff(uuid); //This takes several seconds to execute
        return StatusCode(200);
    }
    public Task InitialiseStuff(string uuid)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            Debug.WriteLine(uuid);
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: @HarryStuart `Task.Factory.StartNew` will create a new thread for the action.